# Visa entry requirement for Vietnam

Tags: visas

My wife and I are UK citizens travelling to Vietnam for 11 days as tourists on 25th October 2017 (we will be flying in from China, which we are first visiting).

Could anyone please tell us if we need a tourist visa for Vietnam? Our understanding is that we do not.

Comment: I was last there in 2004.  At that time, you needed a visa on arrival.  This meant some annoying bureaucracy and a fee but it was possible to just go there.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you don't if you are a British citizen. See [this page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vietnam#Visa_exemption) referencing [this page on a Vietnamese government site](http://lanhsuvietnam.gov.vn/Lists/BaiViet/B%C3%A0i%20vi%E1%BA%BFt/DispForm.aspx?List=dc7c7d75-6a32-4215-afeb-47d4bee70eee&ID=306).